# How can I warp images using optical flow in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, opticalflow

I do not know how to warp image using optical flow in Tensorflow.

In MXnet we can use `mx.sym.GridGenerator` and `mx.sym.BilinearSampler` to implement it. But there are these APIs in tensorflow.

And I wonder why tensorflow has most users but no these API in it. Instead MXnet has these API.

Comment: There's a TensorFlow implementation at https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/transformer (specifically https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/transformer/spatial_transformer.py).

Comment: I was able to implement it by slightly modifying code mentioned above, here's the implementation https://github.com/rajat95/Optical-Flow-Warping-Tensorflow

Answer (score 2):

Try [Spatial Transformer Network](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/transformer), which is part of tensorflow now:

```
from spatial_transformer import transformer
transformed = transformer(x, theta, out_size)
```